# Can I control depths in `Inner`?

Tags: matrix, tensors, operators

I want to optimize the code like this:

```
matmul[a_, b_] :=
{{vecmul[a[[1, 1]], b[[1, 1]]] + vecmul[a[[1, 2]], b[[2, 1]]], 
  vecmul[a[[1, 1]], b[[1, 2]]] + vecmul[a[[1, 2]], b[[2, 2]]]}, 
 {vecmul[a[[2, 1]], b[[1, 1]]] + vecmul[a[[2, 2]], b[[2, 1]]], 
  vecmul[a[[2, 1]], b[[1, 2]]] + vecmul[a[[2, 2]], b[[2, 2]]]}}
```

where `a` and `b` are matrices each of whose entries are vectors (of dimensions equal to each other but unrelated to dimensions of the matrices), and `vecmul` operates on pairs of such vectors. Say, each `a[[i, j]]` and each `b[[i, j]]` is a 7-dimensional vector.

I've tried

```
matmul[a_, b_] := Inner[vecmul[#1, #2] &, a, b]
```

but unfortunately `Inner` views `a` and `b` as tensors with three indices, tries to contract the last index of the first tensor with the first index of the last tensor and fails since they are of different dimensions. The version `Inner[f, tensor1, tensor2, Plus, k]` contracts `k`th index of `tensor1` with the first index of `tensor2` which in my case either gives wrong results (for `k` equal to 1 or 2) or an error (for `k` equal to 3, which is the default value in this case).

So what can I do to avoid these ugly endless redundant repetitions in the code?

Answer (score 2):

My first guess is

```
matmul2[a_, b_] := TensorContract[ Outer[vecmul, a, Transpose[b], 2], {2, 4}]
```

Surprisingly, the idomatic way

```
matmul3[a_, b_] := Table[
  Sum[vecmul[a[[i, j]], b[[j, k]]], {j, 1, Dimensions[a][[2]]}]
  , {i, 1, Dimensions[a][[1]]}, {k, 1, Dimensions[b][[2]]}]
```

seems to be quite a bit faster for large arrays.

But much faster is the following:

```
With[{dot = vecmul},
  cvecmul = Compile[{{x, _Real, 2}, {y, _Real, 2}},
    Total@Table[dot[x[[j]], y[[j]]], {j, 1, Length[x]}],
    CompilationTarget -> "WVM"
    ]
  ];
matmul4[a_, b_] := Outer[cvecmul, a, Transpose[b], 1];
```

If you have a C compiler installed then you can also change
`CompilationTarget -> "WVM"` to `CompilationTarget -> "C"` to get a further speedup.

In the case that `vecmul` is really `Dot` and nothing more fancy, you can fully vectorize everything with

```
matmul5[a_, b_] := Dot[
  Flatten[a, {{1}, {2, 3}}],
  Flatten[Transpose[b, {1, 3, 2}], 1]
 ];
```

Here is a short test suite:

```
vecmul = Dot;
n = 30;
m = 20;
nn = 40;
a = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, m, nn}];
b = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {m, n, nn}];
vecmul = Dot;

aa2 = matmul2[a, b]; // RepeatedTiming
aa3 = matmul3[a, b]; // RepeatedTiming
aa4 = matmul4[a, b]; // RepeatedTiming
aa5 = matmul5[a, b]; // RepeatedTiming

Max[Abs[aa2 - aa3]]
Max[Abs[aa2 - aa4]]
Max[Abs[aa2 - aa5]]
```

> {0.10, Null}
>
> {0.037, Null}
>
> {0.0072, Null}
>
> {0.00029, Null}
>
> 0.
>
> 1.06581*10^-14
>
> 1.77636*10^-14

An explanation for the poor performance of `matmul2` might be that `Outer` has to allocate roughly `m^2 = 400` times the amount of memory compared to what the `Outer` in the `matmul3` has to allocate.

**Edit**

For the function `vecmul` prescribed by the OP in one of the comments, an integer variant of `matmul4` should do the trick.

```
rg = 7;
ng = 12;
vecmul = With[{r = rg, n = ng},
   Compile[{{x, _Integer, 1}, {y, _Integer, 1}},
    Table[Mod[RotateRight[y, k].x, n], {k, 0, r - 1}],
    CompilationTarget -> "WVM"
    ]
   ];    
With[{dot = vecmul},
  cvecmul = Compile[{{x, _Integer, 2}, {y, _Integer, 2}},
    Total@Table[dot[x[[j]], y[[j]]], {j, 1, Length[x]}],
    CompilationTarget -> "WVM"
    ]
  ];
matmul4[a_, b_] := Outer[cvecmul, a, Transpose[b], 1];
```

Comment: Unfortunately in my case it is not `Dot`, rather it is the product in the group algebra of a cyclic group over a cyclic ring, `vecmul[a_, b_] := Mod[a.NestList[RotateRight, b, r - 1], n]` with fixed natural numbers `r` and `n` (`r` is a prime, but `n` not in general). In particular, it is a vector of the same type again, so that `matmul[a, b]` is also the matrix of vectors of the same type.

Comment: Do you mean `vecmul[a_, b_] := Mod[NestList[RotateRight, b, r - 1].a, n]`?

Comment: No it is correct as written. `b.NestList[RotateRight, a, r-1]` gives the same result (the multiplication is commutative). It is supposed to represent the product of $a_1+a_2x+...+a_rx^{r-1}$ and $b_1+b_2x+...+b_rx^{r-1}$ where $x^r=1$ holds

Comment: But the dimensions do not fit...

Comment: Oops sorry I forgot to say that `r` is actually equal to the lengths of both `a` and `b`!